# Proving formula for distance between 2 parallel lines

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I am given the equation $|\frac{c_1-c_2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}|$ to find the distance between 2 parallel lines, $ax+by+c_1=0$ and $ax+by+c_2=0$.  I would like to know how this formula was derived.  Normally, when finding the distance between 2 parallel lines, I would use Pythagoras' theorem, I have no idea how this equation was derived.

Comment: Suppose I give you two parallel lines; how would you go about finding the distance between them? what would you physically do?

Comment: I would use pythagoras' theorem

Comment: For which triangle?

Comment: I have the gradient, I can draw a vertical and horizontal line connecting both lines, forming a triangle

Comment: Good. Can you write down expressions for the points on the two lines connected by your lines?

Comment: use the Hessian Normalform

Comment: @uniquesolution I see where you are getting now!  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you know how to find the distance from a point to a line? There is a very similar-looking formula for that. The formula in your question is just the difference between the signed distances of the origin from the two lines.

Comment: For reference, there is a WP page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_between_two_parallel_lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vector perpendicular to the lines is $(a,b)$, so the unit vector perpendicular to the lines is $\mathbf u = (a, b)/\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$.  Your two lines are given by $(x,y) \cdot \mathbf u = -c_i/\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ for $i = 1, 2$.  In particular the multiple of the unit vector $\mathbf u$ which lies on the $i$-th line is $\mathbf p_i = -c_i/\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \mathbf u$.  What you want is the length of $\mathbf p_1 - \mathbf p_2$, which is  given by your formula.

Exercise:  find and prove a similar formula for the distance between parallel planes.

Addendum:  given the discussion in the comments, you may be happier with a slightly different solution, also using the unit vector $\mathbf u$.  Find one point $\mathbf q_i$ ($i = 1, 2$) on each line.  For example, if $a \ne 0$, you can find the unique point with zero $y$ coordinate. The distance is $\left | (\mathbf q_1 - \mathbf q_2)\cdot \mathbf u \right |$.  The case $a = 0$ has to be handled separately.