# Distance between two parallel lines by having linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I wonder where does this formula is coming from?
It is for finding the distance between two parallel lines when we have their linear equation:
First line is:$ax+by+c=0$
Second line is:$ax+by+c_1=0$
Their distance :$$\frac{|c-c_1|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving formula for distance between 2 parallel lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2609172/proving-formula-for-distance-between-2-parallel-lines)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Calculate the [distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line) of each line from the origin that is

$$d=\frac{|a\cdot0+b\cdot0+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\frac{|c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

than take

- $|d_1-d_2|$ for the line on the same side ($c$ and $c_1$ have same sign)
- $|d_1+d_2|$ for the line on diffent sides ($c$ and $c_1$ have different sign)

from which the given formula is obtained.

Comment: Actually I wanted to ask about for the formula you have just used for calculating distance of a point (origin in your case)from a line. Where does it come from?

Comment: Ah ok, for that I've just given the link here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line (click on "distance") whwre you can find the proof for the standard formula. Please don't hesiste to ask for any other clarification!

Comment: Anyway if your aim is that you should re-formulate the OP as "Distance between a point and a line" and not "Distance between two parallel lines by having linear equations". It should be more clear to understand what you are asking for.

Comment: Take also a look here for related topic with proof https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85761/distance-between-a-point-and-a-line

Comment: Shouldn't this$|d_1-d_2|$ be $|d_1+d_2|$because once we have calculated distance from origin we would add them to have total distance from each other

Comment: @Abbas Think to the case with $c=c_1$ in this case the distance is equal to 0 then we need to take $|c-c_1|$. Of course the $|d_1-d_2|$ must be interpreted according to the sign of $c$ and $c_1$ but the final formula is correct.

Comment: @Abbas I've added a more correct and detailed explanation on this point.

Comment: Then it should be $||c|-|c_1||$in numerator. Shouldn't be equal to $|c-c_1|$

Comment: If line are on the same side $||c|-|c_1||=|c-c_1|$ if are on different sides $||c|+|c_1||=|c-c_1|$.

Comment: But isn't the formula skiping this fact?

Comment: @Abbas as you can see, in any case at the numerator we have $|c-c_1|=|c_1-c|$ thus the formula always works!

Comment: @Abbas What is the extra information? Try with some simple example to see how it works for example y+x=1 and y+x=3 or y+x=-2.

Comment: You are right. I tried and convinced myself(there was sth that I couldn't understand now I do.)thank you.

Comment: Well done, You are welcome! Bye

Comment: gimusi.As usual I refer to your answer.:)))

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively: the perpendicular line that passes through origin is: $bx-ay=0$. It crosses the two parallel lines at:
$$\left(-\frac{ac}{a^2+b^2},-\frac{bc}{a^2+b^2}\right) \ \ \text{and} \ \ \left(-\frac{ac_1}{a^2+b^2},-\frac{bc_1}{a^2+b^2}\right).$$
The distance between these points is:
$$d=\sqrt{\left(\frac{a(c-c_1)}{a^2+b^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{b(c-c_1)}{a^2+b^2}\right)^2}=\frac{|c-c_1|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $ax+by+c=0$, assume $a,b,c \not =0.$

$y=0$: $X-$intercept: $x=-c/a;$

$x=0:$ $Y-$intercept: $y =-c/b.$

$A(-c/a,0); B(0,-c/b);$ $O(0,0);$

form a right $\triangle ABO$ with

lengths of legs $|c/a|$ and $|c/b|.$

Lenght of hypotenuse : $\sqrt{(c/a)^2+(c/b)^2}.$

Height, $h$,  on $AB$ is the desired distance to the origin:

Area of $\triangle ABO$ :

Area $= (1/2)|c/a||c/b| = (1/2)h\sqrt{(c/a)^2+(c/b)^2}.$

Solve for $h:$

$h= \dfrac{c^2}{|ab|}\dfrac {|ab|}{|c|\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)}}$.

$h =\dfrac{|c|}{a^2+b^2}$.

Left to do :

The above gives you the  distance of one line from the origin, regardless of the sign of $c.$

Now you have 2 lines , with $c,c _1.$

Find the distance between them.

(Does gimusi's answer help?)

Comment: Thanks for the quote Peter, nice derivation!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative suppose wlog that $b\neq 0$ then translate vertically with $by\to by-c_1$ and obtain

- $ax+by+c=0\to ax+by+c-c_1=0$
- $ax+by+c_1\to ax+by=0$

then the distance between the two lines is equal to the distance of the translated line $ax+by+c-c_1=0$ from the origin that is indeed the given expression.