# How to calculate distance between two parallel lines?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Suppose there are two parallel lines: $w_1x_1+w_2x_2=c_1$ (Line 1) and $w_1x_1+w_2x_2=c_2$ (Line 2). What is the distance between them (the shortest distance between any two points)?

I know the answer is $d=\frac{|c_1-c_2|}{||w||}$ where $||w||=\sqrt{w_1^2+w_2^2}$.

The method I was going to calculate is as follows:

1) find any point on Line 1 $(x_1^0,x_2^0)$ such that $w_1x_1^0+w_2x_2^0=c_1$

2) calculate the perpendicular line (Line 3) to Line 1 and passing through $(x_1^0,x_2^0)$

3) find the point $(x_1^1,x_2^1)$ where Line 3 intersects Line 2

4) calculate the distance between $(x_1^0,x_2^0)$ and $(x_1^1,x_2^1)$

However I couldn't figure out the algebra of this method. Can someone show me the steps of the above calculation? Or is there any simpler way to calculate this? Thanks.

Comment: I would say sipler way to calculate distance between two parallel lines you wrote in the introduction of the query.

Comment: Line 3 given by $w_2x_1-w_1x_2=0$ is through the origin and perpendicular to Line 1 and Line 2; can you find the distance from the origin to the intersection of Line 1 (and Line 2) with Line 3 ?

Comment: Which step are you having trouble with?   Perpendicular is of form $w_2x_1-w_1x_2=c$,.where $c=w_2x_1^0-w_1x_2^0$.

Comment: Since you're doing linear algebra, the simplest method is to realize that $w_1x_1+w_2x_2$ is simply the inner product (aka dot product) of $(w_1,w_2)$ with $(x_1,x_2)$ and that the vector $(w_1,w_2)$ is orthogonal to both lines. Also, the inner product of $(w_1,w_2)$ with any point's position vector gives you the (scaled) distance from the line $w_1x_2+w_2x_2=0,$ scaled by $\|w\|.$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving formula for distance between 2 parallel lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2609172/proving-formula-for-distance-between-2-parallel-lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible way: Let $(a_1, a_2)$ be a point on $w_1x_1+w_2x_2-c_1=0$. Then we want to minimalize
$$f(x)=(x_1-a_1)^2+(x_2-a_2)^2$$
With the constraint
$$g(x)=w_1x_1+w_2x_2-c_2=0$$
Using Lagrange multipliers:
$$\nabla f + 2\lambda\nabla g = 0$$
The derivatives are
$$\nabla f=[2(x_1-a_1), 2(x_2-a_2)]$$
$$\nabla g = [w_1, w_2]$$
Which means that
$$2(x_1-a_1)+2\lambda w_1=0$$
$$2(x_2-a_2)+2\lambda w_2=0$$
So the system of equations we need to solve is
$$x_1=-\lambda w_1+a_1$$
$$x_2=-\lambda w_2+a_2$$
$$w_1x_1+w_2x_2=c_2$$
Which has the following solution:
$$x_1=\frac{-a_2w_1w_2+a_1w_2^2+c_2w_1}{w_1^2+w_2^2}$$
$$x_2=\frac{-a_1w_1w_2+a_2w_1^2+c_2w_2}{w_1^2+w_2^2}$$
$$\lambda=\frac{a_1w_1+a_2w_2-c_2}{w_1^2+w_2^2}$$
So the minimal distance squared is
\begin{align}
d^2
&=\left(\frac{-a_2w_1w_2+a_1w_2^2+c_2w_1}{w_1^2+w_2^2}-a_1\right)^2+\left(\frac{-a_1w_1w_2+a_2w_1^2+c_2w_2}{w_1^2+w_2^2}-a_2\right)^2\\
&=\left(\frac{-a_2w_1w_2+a_1w_2^2+c_2w_1}{w_1^2+w_2^2}-\frac{a_1w_1^2+a_1w_2^2}{w_1^2+w_2^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{-a_1w_1w_2+a_2w_1^2+c_2w_2}{w_1^2+w_2^2}-\frac{a_2w_1^2+a_2w_2^2}{w_1^2+w_2^2}\right)^2\\
&=\left(\frac{-a_2w_1w_2-a_1w_1^2+c_2w_1}{w_1^2+w_2^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{-a_1w_1w_2-a_2w_2^2+c_2w_2}{w_1^2+w_2^2}\right)^2\\
&=\left(\frac{-c_1w_1+c_2w_1}{w_1^2+w_2^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{-c_1w_2+c_2w_2^2}{w_1^2+w_2}\right)^2\\
&=\frac{(-c_1w_1+c_2w_1)^2+(-c_1w_2+c_2w_2)^2}{(w_1^2+w_2^2)^2}\\
&= \frac{(c_2-c_1)^2}{w_1^2+w_2^2}
\end{align}
As we expected.

Comment: Thanks for this excellent answer. I changed the selected answer to this one because I was looking for a solution that started closer from first principals.

Comment: @Catiger3331 thank you :) To be honest, this answer is a bit far away from linear algebra and geometry, and more calculation-heavy; But I like this method because of my geometry skills are not so great :)

Comment: I like this and this is similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_between_two_straight_lines

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to figure out the distance from the right triangle formed by one of the lines, the vertical axis and the distance-line itself, as shown in the graph.

The intersections of the vertical axis with the two lines are $-c_1/w_2$ and $-c_2/w_2$, respectively. 
And the tangent of the two line is $\tan\theta=-w_1/w_2$.
According to the right triangle in the graph.
the distance $d$ is simply,

$$d=|c_1/w_2-c_2/w_2|\cos\theta=\frac{|(c_1-c_2)/w_2|}{\sqrt{1+w_1^2/w_2^2}}=\frac{|c_1-c_2|}{\sqrt{w_1^2+w_2^2}}$$

where $\cos\theta=1/\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}$ is used.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is an easier way to find the distance using dot product.

Pick the point $A=(x_1,y_1)$ on the fist line and $B=(x_2,y_2)$ on the second line.

The distance between the lines is the length of the projection of $AB$ on the normal vector to the parallel lines

$$d=\frac {|AB.N|}{||N||}=\frac {|c_2-c_1|}{\sqrt {w_1^2+w_2^2}}$$

You may fill in the details of simplifying the dot product and the norm in the above fraction.

Answer (score 0):

The distance between two parallel lines $a x+b y+c_{1}=0$ and
$$
a x+b y+c_{2}=0 \text { is }=\frac{\left|c_{1}-c_{2}\right|}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}
$$
(Note: The coefficients of $x \& y$ in both equations should be same)